# typescript define/create new type as a variable?

Tags: typescript

I have this type

```
{timeStamp: number, rectangle:number[]}
```

and I want to use it multiple times(within the same file),
is there any way to do it like:

```
type detectionParams = {timeStamp: number, rectangle:number[]};
private detection: detectionParams[];
```

Comment: Exactly like that, actually. Note that the convention is that types begin with a Capital letter, so `type DetectionParams = ...` would be better.

Comment: ohh, I just placed it in the wrong place... Thanks for reassuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a plain object type, rather than using the type alias its more common to use an interface instead.

```
interface DetectionParams {
    timeStamp: number;
    rectangle: number[];
};
```

If any other files are to use this Object structure, just export it.